# Show different text from option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, ionic-framework

I have a dropdown with all countries and their phone code. My drop down as a limited space, so the text must be short.

When the dropdown is open, I want to show the the country name and the phone code, but when a user select an option, I only want to show the phone code on the dropdown as the selected value.

```
<select ng-model="country" ng-options="c.phoneNumberCountryCode as (c.countryName + ' (+' + c.phoneNumberCountryCode + ')' ) for c in countriesList">           
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0fadq61k/

Comment: from where that "country" is comming in `ng-model` ?

Answer (score 1):

I would combine `ng-selected` with `ng-click` in an attempt to achieve this. The problem with `ng-click` (inherent in Angular itself) is that while it does refresh your whole list, it does not refresh the already selected item. I would suggest that you change your design. One thing you could do is use for example the first 3 letters of the country name, or a similar combination. Place the following code in your fiddle to see an example:

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">     
     <select ng-model="country" ng-options="c.phoneNumberCountryCode as (c.countryName + ' (+' + c.phoneNumberCountryCode + ')' ) for c in countriesList" ng-selected="onCodeSelected(country)" ng-click="onClick()">           
     </select>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

function Ctrl($scope) {

  //this should be in a service
  $scope.countriesList = [{
    id: 0,
    countryName: 'Portugal',
    phoneNumberCountryCode: '351'
  }, {
    id: 1,
    countryName: 'Spain',
    phoneNumberCountryCode: '34'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    countryName: 'UK',
    phoneNumberCountryCode: '44'
      }, {
    id: 3,
    countryName: 'Australia',
    phoneNumberCountryCode: '61'
  }]; 

    $scope.onClick = function () {
    //refresh data from service instead of hardcoded like below
        $scope.countriesList[0].countryName = "Portugal";
      $scope.countriesList[1].countryName = "Spain";
      $scope.countriesList[2].countryName = "UK";
      $scope.countriesList[3].countryName = "Australia";
  }

    $scope.onCodeSelected = function(countryCode) {
    if (countryCode) {
     angular.forEach($scope.countriesList, function(value, key) {
        if (value.phoneNumberCountryCode === countryCode) {
            var countryShort = $scope.countriesList[value.id].countryName.substring(0, 3);
            $scope.countriesList[value.id].countryName = countryShort;
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution is almost perfect. The only problem is that after choosing a country and then reopening the dropdown, the previously selected country also have the text changed on the list. I will try to figure out.

Comment: Yes, that's the issue I was mentioning. I don't think Angular has a way to refresh the name of the selected country when you reopen the dropdown, which is why I went with the first three letters. Otherwise it's easy enough to remove the whole name completely and just show the phone code, but then the user would have no clue which code they were on.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">     

    <select ng-options="item as item.id for item in items" ng-model="selected"
      ng-change="dispThis(selected)"
    ></select> {{output}}        

<div>
```

and in script

```
  var app = angular.module('app', []);

function Ctrl($scope) {

  $scope.items = [{
    label: 'Portugal',
    id: '351'
  }, {
    label: 'Spain',
    id: '34'
  }];  


  $scope.dispThis = function(c){

      console.log(c);
      $scope.output = "Country: "+c.label+" & Ph.code "+
            c.id

    };
}
```

Comment: Sorry i am not authorized to log into fiddle to code.